# getBoundingClientRect within svg incorrect only on Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, svg, getboundingclientrect

When calling `getBoundingClientRect` of a div within an svg in order to position other elements outside of the svg accordingly, the `top` and `left` values are too high only on Chrome (78.0.3904.108) and Windows 10.

[Here is a codepen to demonstrate the problem](https://codepen.io/l4xecz/pen/ExxrrVd). The red border around the green box is positioned using the `getBoundingClientRect` coordinates of the element within the svg. On Windows Chrome, you'll see the result of the `top` and `left` values being inflated somehow (first screenshot below). In other browsers it behaves as expected (second screenshot). Is there a better way to achieve this, or is there a reason for why this issue only appears in Windows Chrome?

[image: Windows Chrome behavior]
[image: All other browsers]

**Update:** Adding code snippet.

```js
const svg = document.querySelector('.svg');
const ref = document.querySelector('.ref');
const outer = document.querySelector('.outer');
const refRect = ref.getBoundingClientRect();

console.log('.svg BoundingClientRect', svg.getBoundingClientRect());
console.log('.ref BoundingClientRect', refRect);

$(outer).css('top', refRect.top - window.scrollY)
$(outer).css('left', refRect.left - window.scrollX)
```

```css
svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.ref {
  background: #ccffcc;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.outer {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg class="svg" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <foreignObject x="18%" y="14%" width="100" height="100">
    <div class="ref">This should be perfectly surrounded by a red border</div>
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
<div class="outer"></div>
```

Comment: what version? it seems fine on my chrome (windows also and last version)

Comment: Windows 10 Home 1809

Comment: Please include all code necessary to reproduce the issue here on Stack Overflow. Note that you can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (the icon has `<>` on it in the editor). Then people can try it out here on Stack Overflow.